# New Servlet 3.0 global error page feature does not work on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, error-handling, tomcat7

The Servlet 3.0 specification states that a global error message can be listed in the `web.xml` to encompass all server errors.

Example:

```xml
<error-page>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Old Method:

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

When adding this new method to my `web.xml` in Tomcat 7, it does not work. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That'll be a bug in Tomcat 7. It works fine on Glassfish 3, for example.

It's time to report a bug to Tomcat guys, so I did: [issue 52135](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52135).

---

**Update**: it has been closed because the Servlet spec was "not clear" that `<exception-type>` and `<error-code>` became optional. This was only shown in figure 14-10 of the [Servlet 3.0 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) and nowhere literally in the text, even though the new Servlet 3.0 XSD confirms this change. This was later been reopened and a link to a [nice blog article](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_136_default_error_page) was posted which confirms this only once more. Now we have only to wait for the Tomcat developers to really fix it. Based on the Tomcat source code as far as I can see, it's not going to be a trivial fix and that was perhaps why it was closed so soon.

---

**Update 2**: this has finally been fixed and implemented in Tomcat 7.0.29.

Comment: This is what I suspected.  Thank you for submitting the issue!

Comment: The issue you opened was closed because it was not specific enough.

Comment: I've posted a comment afterwards. Feel free to repost the issue with a link to the old issue. I'm not going to argue with Tomcat guys again.

Comment: It looks like the team reopened this as an enhancement as of 7.0.22.  It remains open.

Comment: Tomcat version was just the one at the time when the issue was reported. It's currently already at 7.0.27.

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbling upon this doesn't think to check the bug linked in the answer, this issue is now fixed as of 7.0.29: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html I'm using 7.0.35 and global error pages work perfectly.