# Error pages with Servlet 3.0

Tags: spring, servlets, web.xml, servlet-3.0

In the `web.xml` file, I'm trying to specify an error page as follows.

```
<error-page>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I expect it to go without an error code according to Servlet 3.0 but it doesn't. I have to explicitly specify an appropriate error code for it to work something like the following.

```
<error-page>
    <description>Missing page</description>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Why doesn't the former approach work with Servlet 3.0?

---

I have upgraded NetBeans 7.2.1. It supports Apache Tomcat 7.0.27.0 which has Servlet 3.0 API.

By the way, I have disabled the HTTP Monitor as it raises the following warning.

> MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in
>   the chain.

It happened when I used Spring security in my application and it was reported as a [jira](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204775) issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997286/new-servlet-3-0-global-error-page-feature-does-not-work-on-tomcat-7). I never personally made this

```
<error-page>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

working on Tomcat 7, as for the bug described in the link I gave you. <strike>I don't know if Apache solved it in later version of Tomcat, but I doubt</strike>.
My previous statement was probably wrong. Digging a bit, I found this: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52135 and the problem should have been solved in Tomcat 7.0.29, so your only solution is to update to post-29 version.
Here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html, in the changelog for version 7.0.29 you can read why there was such an issue:

> Add support for a default error page to be defined in web.xml by
>   defining an error page with just a nested location element. It appears
>   this feature was intended to be included in the Servlet 3.0
>   specification but was accidently left out. (markt)

Comment: I have just downloaded [Apache Tomcat 7.0.35](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi#7.0.35) in which the approach worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it works. Your question moved me to try again, so thank you too!