# filterchain on jsf + PrettyFaces + spring security

Tags: java, spring, jsf, redirect, jsf-2

in jsf I normally can return a String inside a function that is automatically used for a redirect.

For example: 
Java:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@Component
public class TestController implements Serializable {
    public String testButton(){  
        return "index";  
    }
}
```

xHTML:

```
<h:form>  
    <p:commandButton value="return to index" actionListener="#{testController.testButton}" ajax="false" />  
</h:form>
```

So if someone presses the button with the description `return to index` he will be redirected to `/index` on the Server.
Of course this can also be achieved with a normal Link, but I am using this method in many ways, for example the redirect after a login, ...

This way of redirecting worked until I decided to include `PrettyFaces` to the project. I set up everything I needed and since then this kind of String-return based redirect does not longer work.

When I now call such a method, he only reloads the current page, but stays on the page. no redirect to any other page at all.

Also, I am getting a little warning in the console since then:

```
MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in the chain.
```

This let me to the idea, that my filterchain is not correctly set up.

My `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- "normal" Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml
            classpath:spring/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- filterchain -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Error Page 404 -->
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.xhtml?errorID=404</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

So now my concrete questions:

1. Does the warning comes from a wrong filterchain configuration?
2. How can I configure the filterchain correct? In my way of thinking it must be **Spring security** -> **PrettyFaces** -> **"normal" JSF** as pipeline for a request. If this thought is correct, how can I achieve this?
3. Why can I only set a xhtml-path link as error 404 document and not a PrettyFaces URL? Is this also a problem because of a bad filterchain?

Thanks so much for any help :)
greetings,
Christopher

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26540064/1391249

Comment: Apart from that, there are too many annotations above the managed bean.