# Java error page does not work (apache tomcat 7)

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I have a problem with tomcat server. OS - Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Echo by version.sh

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Server built:   Apr 1 2013 08:32:04
Server number:  7.0.26.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.5.0-23-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_25-b15
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

So that i have tomcat 7 running app and java 1.7.0 JDK.

In my web.xml defined error-page:

```
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <error-page>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Error page is mapped - there is all ok. It works if I opened it manually.
But where I am trying to get some error (for example 404) - I am getting default tomcat 404 page.

Where in web.xml I defined

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

I saw my error page. Servlets 3 supports global error pages with only location. And I need it. But its not working... Why???

In my pom.xml defined servlet-api:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.26</version>
</dependency>
```

And on my localhost tomcat (7.0.41) started with IDEA all works. But where I am deploying my app to ubuntu server - error page does not want to work...

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have hit this issue: [New Servlet 3.0 global error page feature does not work on Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997286/new-servlet-3-0-global-error-page-feature-does-not-work-on-tomcat-7), assuming the Ubuntu Tomcat version is < 7.0.29.

Comment: Thanks a log. Really - I installed tomcat 7.0.41 and all works fine :)